# How to pass NSManagedObjectContext back up to root view in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, core-data, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I may just be passing data between views completely wrong here, so I am open to completely changing how I pass my data back and forth.

My app delegate creates the NSManagedObjectContext and passes that to my main menu using a UINavigationController which makes it the root view:

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    // Handle the error.
}
// Pass the managed object context to the view controller.
mainMenuViewController.managedObjectContext = context;

UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController];
self.theNavController = aNavigationController;

[[self theNavController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

[window addSubview:theNavController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[mainMenuViewController release];
[aNavigationController release];
```

Then when they select a different view controller from the main menu, I initialize the new view controller, pass the NSManagedObjectContext to it, then push it onto the UINavigationController:

```
BombsViewController *bombsViewController = [[BombsViewController alloc] init];
bombsViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bombsViewController animated:YES];
[bombsViewController release];
```

All is fine until I decide to go back to the main menu from my BombsViewController.  I am attempting to use the following to pop the root view controller back onto the UINavigationController:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, I can't see a way to send the root view controller my NSManagedObjectContext back since the popToRootViewControllerAnimated method doesn't accept a view.  I tried using the popToViewController:animated: method but then the app crashes with a "**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'**", "**Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.**":

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
mainMenuViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES];
[mainMenuViewController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you send it back?  Your root view controller has not been `-dealloc`'ed so it still exists in memory and still has a reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext`.  There is nothing to pass back.

The error you are getting is not Core Data related. Run it in the debugger and set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and see where it is crashing.

Comment: I was under the impression that view controllers were automatically dealloc'd when they were no longer the current focus of the UINavigationController.  Guess that changes everything.

Comment: They are released only when they are removed from the stack.  When you push another view on top it does not release the view underneath.  When you pop a view controller off the stack then it is released.